# Dart to WASM compilation

Tags: dart, webassembly

I'm trying to build dart to wasm (to use w/ fermyon spin)
for example let's say I create a command line app

```
dart create -t console example
```

how can I run `dart compile` to output a `wasm` file?

##### note

This [clip from wasmIO](https://youtu.be/Nkjc9r0WDNo?t=1219) hints at the possibility of building dart to wasm already,
but the [documentation](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/pkg/dart2wasm/dart2wasm.md) seems missing.

#### bounty notes

I'll accept the best answer that provides the steps to build to wasm
a dart "hello world" app
eg: `dart create -t console example`
using `dart compile` with the appropriate flags

Comment: Do you object to using Flutter as your tool base?

Comment: I do object, this has nothing to do with `flutter', I'm trying to understand how compile a dart project (dart create -t console example) to wasm

Comment: It is not possible at the moment, as dart2wasm is not released yet. You can try it, however setup might be difficult. See here for details: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/main/pkg/dart2wasm

Comment: I tried this so I can give out the build steps but when I download the SDK and open with VSCode all of the packages break. None of the imports are working and packages do not see even their own lib folder. I could get a wasm export using dart compiler though. You can use the command that is shared here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32894#issuecomment-1326159646   Basically you run `dartaotruntime  path-to-sdk/bin/snapshots/dart2wasm_product.snapshot --dart-sdk pathtosdk inputfile.dart outputfile.wasm`

Answer (score 1):

### Introduction

As mentioned in [dart2wasm module](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/main/pkg/dart2wasm), you already can build dart files to wasm using the command `dart --enable-asserts pkg/dart2wasm/bin/dart2wasm.dart infile.dart outfile.wasm` e.g. for the console example `dart --enable-asserts pkg/dart2wasm/bin/dart2wasm.dart options bin/example.dart ~/output.wasm`. It is not included in the docs because it is an EXPERIMENTAL feature that does not even have its own command and needs ao enable an assert.

### To solve your issue

***CHECKOUT THE REPO USING [GOOGLE FETCH](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/wiki/Building#getting-the-source) AND NOT SIMPLY CLONE THE REPO DEPENDENCIES WILL BE BROKEN IF YOU DID THAT***

Change `bin/example.dart` into this

```dart
import 'package:example/example.dart' as example;

@pragma("wasm:export")
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  print('Hello world: ${example.calculate()}!');
}
```

Change `lib/example.dart` into this

```dart
@pragma("wasm:export")
int calculate() {
  return 6 * 7;
}
```

Run the following commands in the terminal

```bash
cd WHATAEVER_DIRECTORY_PROJECT_IS_IN
dart --enable-asserts pkg/dart2wasm/bin/dart2wasm.dart options bin/example.dart ~/output.wasm
```

Change ~/output.wasm to whereever you want it to be in
Then you may run your wasm using d8 with your mjs.
Or actually run in a browser:
With the Wasm module instance in inst, these can be called as:

```js
inst.exports.main();
inst.exports.calculate();
```

Untested because I have issues with google fetch google is banned in my country. Comment if you got problems! Click on the trophy to bounty&checkmark to accept&upvote if you liked the answer!

Answer (score -1):

At the time of writing, you can compile Dart to WebAssembly using a checkout of the SDK's `main` branch.

First, download the Dart source code as described in the [wiki](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/wiki/Building#getting-the-source).
Next, enter the source directory and run `dart2wasm` with `dart --enable-asserts pkg/dart2wasm/bin/dart2wasm.dart infile.dart outfile.wasm`.

Full instructions can be found here: [Running dart2wasm](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/64fcb8de1b40094a3dc1529d3ce9dfd01b7a790e/pkg/dart2wasm#running-dart2wasm)

Comment: for my understanding this solution outputs both a .wasm and a .mjs as framework
that needs to run using `d8` (engine?), so it's basically useless for real wasm use cases (eg: fermyon spin). I was looking for a solution that just outputs ONLY a .wasm file